# Python package dependency tree

Tags: python, dependency-management, pypi

I would like to analyze the dependency tree of Python packages.  How can I obtain this data?

Things I already know

1. `setup.py` sometimes contains a `requires` field that lists package dependencies
2. PyPi is an online repository of Python packages
3. PyPi has an API

Things that I don't know

1. Very few projects (around 10%) on PyPi explicitly list dependencies in the `requires` field but `pip/easy_install` still manage to download the correct packages.  What am I missing?  For example the popular library for statistical computing, `pandas`, doesn't list `requires` but still manages to install `numpy`, `pytz`, etc.... Is there a better way to automatically collect the full list of dependencies?
2. Is there a pre-existing database somewhere?  Am I repeating existing work?
3. Do similar, easily accessible, databases exist for other languages with distribution systems (R, Clojure, etc...?)

Comment: Your question, as it stands, is actually too broad. Don't put too many questions into a post, and keep it practical and answerable. Your point 3. invites debate and shopping lists rather than concrete answers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be looking at the `install_requires` field *instead*, see [New and changed `setup` keywords](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords).

`requires` is deemed too vague a field to rely on for dependency installation. In addition, there are `setup_requires` and `test_requires` fields for dependencies required for `setup.py` and for running tests.

Certainly, the dependency graph has been analyzed before; from this [blog article by Olivier Girardot](http://ogirardot.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/state-of-the-pythonpypi-dependency-graph/) comes this fantastic image:

[image: PyPI dependencies]
The image is linked to the interactive version of the graph.

Comment: Well, it *is* a very beautiful graph!

Comment: That graph is incredible.

Comment: As beautiful as the graph is, I don't understand how to read it.

Comment: There is also `requires_dist` which I can see in the json api: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Django/json

There are packages like cryptography that use `install_requires' and that info is no in the api: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptography/json

Answer (score 1):

Using tool like [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), you can list all requirements for each package.

The command is:

```
pip install --no-install package_name
```

You can reuse part of pip in your script. The part responsible for parsing requirements is module [`pip.req`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/tree/develop/pip/req).

Comment: I like the idea of using `pip` from within Python.  The command line interface fails if I already have the package installed.  How can I use the Python code directly to find the dependencies of a particular package?

Comment: `--no-install` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it programmatically using python `pip` package:

```
from pip._vendor import pkg_resources  # Ensure pip conf index-url pointed to real PyPi Index

# Get dependencies from pip 
package_name = 'Django'
try:
    package_resources = pkg_resources.working_set.by_key[package_name.lower()] # Throws KeyError if not found
    dependencies = package_resources._dep_map.keys() + ([str(r) for r in package_resources.requires()])
    dependencies = list(set(dependencies))
except KeyError:
    dependencies = []
```

And here is how you can get dependencies from the PyPi API:

```
import requests
import json
package_name = 'Django'
# Package info url
PYPI_API_URL = 'https://pypi.python.org/pypi/{package_name}/json'
package_details_url = PYPI_API_URL.format(package_name=package_name)
response = requests.get(package_details_url)
data = json.loads(response.content)
if response.status_code == 200:
    dependencies = data['info'].get('requires_dist')
    dependencies2 = data['info'].get('requires')
    dependencies3 = data['info'].get('setup_requires')
    dependencies4 = data['info'].get('test_requires')
    dependencies5 = data['info'].get('install_requires')
    if dependencies2:
        dependencies.extend(dependencies2)
    if dependencies3:
        dependencies.extend(dependencies3)
    if dependencies4:
        dependencies.extend(dependencies4)
    if dependencies5:
        dependencies.extend(dependencies5)
    dependencies = list(set(dependencies))
```

You can use recursion to call dependencies of dependencies to get the full tree. Cheers!

Comment: I used this one liner to get the info from the PyPI API: `PKG=requests; curl -L "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/${PKG}/json" | jq '.info | {requires_dist, requires, setup_requires, test_requires, install_requires}'` Obviously, change PKG to whatever you want to look up.