# Pypi, see which package requires a specific package

Tags: python, pypi

How can I get a list of packages that require a specific packages? Specifically I'm trying to find all packages that require [astroid](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/astroid/1.3.7)

Comment: Some answers can be found to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708723/python-package-dependency-tree. Also in order to figure dependecies as an graph you can use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Gluttony/0.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible at the time of writing as PyPI package metadata does not contain this information.

As noted in the comments, you can download all packages and analyse the contents but there is no PyPI API yet that allows you to fetch this information from PyPI.