# Get package's dependencies without installing them

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56938959/14154727), I am able to get the dependencies of  a package. However I am looking for a solution that does not require you to download and install the package.

Is this possible?

**Edit:** I meant getting the package dependencies from PyPI. I want to get the package dependencies from a PyPI package, but my only solution requires me to install the package, which is not what I want. Is it possible to get the package dependencies from PyPI?

Comment: how would that work? you have the package on an hard-drive?

Comment: Whoops! I edited the post- I want the package dependencies from PyPi.

Comment: which package are you trying to install?

Comment: I'm trying to make a program which will spit out the dependencies of a package (without installing the package), and I'm using flask as a test to get it's dependencies.

Comment: I havent tried but seems to be what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147667/is-there-a-way-to-list-pip-dependencies-requirements

Comment: Well that's useful- but I would like to incorporate it with my python script and I probably want a method that doesn't use pip. But I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: [JSON PyPi API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41886445/7976758), found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpypi%5D+API+dependencies. Docs: https://warehouse.pypa.io/api-reference/json/

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, in many cases *PyPI* won't be able to deliver reliable info about the dependencies for a distribution. For example, for *source distributions* the list of dependencies is somewhat dynamic, and the only way to get a definitive static list of dependencies is to build the distribution (run the `setup.py`). Meaning that in some cases there is no way around downloading and building the distributions locally (with the correct Python interpreter). No need to install them though.

---

**Note**:

I believe [`johnnydep`](https://pypi.org/project/johnnydep/) is a tool that does exactly that. But it doesn't answer your question as you are probably looking for a library or an *API*.