# Getting pip dependency versions without installing?

Tags: python, pip

When you tell pip to install multiple packages simultaneously, it looks up all child dependencies and installs the most recent version that is allowed by all parent package restrictions.

For example, if packageA requires child>=0.9 and packageB requires child<=1.1, then pip will install child==1.1.

I'm trying to write a script to scan a `requirements.txt` and pin all unlisted child package versions.

One way to do this would be to simply install everything from a `requirements.txt` file via `pip install -r requirements.txt`, then parse the output of `pip freeze`, and strip out all the packages from my `requirements.txt` file. Everything left should be child packages and the highest version number that pip calculated.

However, this requires creating a Python virtual environment and installing all packages, which can take a bit a time. Is there any option in pip to do the version calculation without actually installing the packages? If not, is there pip-like tool that provides this?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but poetry handles this beautifully

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63900122/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/38531949/7976758 . Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+dependencies+without+install

Answer (score 0):

You can read the package requirements for PyPI hosted packages with the json module:

python3 terminal/script:

```
import csv
import json
import requests

your_package = str('packageA')
pypi_url = 'https://pypi.python.org/pypi/' + your_package + '/json'
data = requests.get(pypi_url).json()

reqs = data['info']['requires_dist']
print(reqs)
print('Writing requirements for ' + your_package + ' to requirements.csv')
f = open('requirements.csv', 'w')
w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
w.writerows([x.split(',') for x in reqs])
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question correctly you’re trying to install a particular version of a package, one way to do this is after specifying the version in ur requirement.txt file, it can be installed by using pip install then the dependency plus the version
example  pip install WhatsApp v3.5

Comment: No, I'm sorry, but this is not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

`pip` has a --dry-run option that tells you what it *would* install given a particular set of requirements, whether listed in the command line or passed in as a `requirements.txt` file via the `-r` option.  Since it sounds like you would want to generate a full list of dependencies, you could also use `--ignore-installed` to ignore any dependencies you already have.  Alternatively, you could just create an empty virtualenv and do your dry run in there.  Since you wouldn't actually be installing anything into it, it shouldn't be that time consuming.

There is also a `--report` option that will let you output a structured JSON report of what was installed (or would have been in the case of a dry run).  The format of that output file is described [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/installation-report/).  It unfortunately does not output a file in the `requirements.txt` format, but since that JSON output is well structured, it would be easy and reliable to generate a `requirements.txt` file from it.  You could use [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) or some other JSON parsing tool to generate it.  For example ...

```
python3 -m pip install --ignore-installed --dry-run -r requirements.txt --report installed.json

jq '.install[] | .metadata.name + "==" + .metadata.version' -r
```

This will output a requirements file just like pip freeze, with all of the requirements pegged to specific versions.  If you didn't want to use `jq` you could even just write a little script in Python using the built-in `json` module to change that report file into a `requirements.txt` file. In either case, you end up with a full, pegged-version list of every dependency that you need, and without ever having to actually install anything.